# Sorting dynamic column(s) with N/A values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) in the project. The table is being populated using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $ajaxurl;?>",
    type: "POST",
    success : function(html){
        $("#response").html(html);
        $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide the loading message
        $('#databuttons').show(); // show the buttons
        var t = $('#table').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            }],
            "deferRender": true,
            "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
            "language": {
              "search": "Search within results:"
            },
            "dom": 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ],
            "responsive":true
        });

        t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
            t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            });
        } ).draw();
        $('.dt-button').css('visibility','hidden');
    }
});
```

Most importantly the number of columns and theirs order are dynamic.

What I want to achieve is sorting across arbitrary column that may contain numeric value as well as 'N/A' value.

Right now sorting is not working properly.

[image: Sorting]

[image]

As depicted in the image the sorting is not proper as some values contain N/A values.

I want N/A to go to the bottom of the table.

I found out a following [tutorial](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35268/how-to-ignore-a-specific-string-or-n-a-for-sorting):

But the issue out here is we have to specify the target :

```
"columnDefs":      [{ type: 'percent', targets: 6 },{ "type": "percent", "targets": 4 }]
```

My table may contain 2 columns, 3 columns so it is dynamic how can I specify targets in that case?

Also I found out absolute sorting [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/absolute)

But the problem is same as we have to specify the target columns.

How to deal with this when we have dynamic columns?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov i have edited my question and added the relevant details as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd **strongly** suggest **NOT TO** use jQuery `$.ajax()` method to populate your DataTable as you will run into whole bunch of issues with that approach. I'd recommend to employ DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option, instead:

```
var t = $('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "<?php echo $ajaxurl;?>",
        type: 'POST'
    },
    ...
});
```

As for your specific problem, it has two parts:

**1.** Get your data sorted in a custom manner;

**2.** Assign custom type (required for sorting) to arbitrary column.

Solution of the first problem, basically, boils down to introducing your custom data type (e.g. `population`), which you specify within `columnDefs`/`columns` option:

```
var t = $('#table').DataTable({
    columns: [
        ...
        {data: 'population', title: 'population', type: 'population'},
    ]
    ...
});
```

With that, you may implement your custom sorting logic:

```
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
      'population-asc': (a,b) => b=='N/A' ? -1: a=='N/A' ? 1 : Number(a.replace(/,/g,''))-Number(b.replace(/,/g,'')),
      'population-desc': (a,b) => b=='N/A' ? -1: a=='N/A' ? 1 : Number(b.replace(/,/g,''))-Number(a.replace(/,/g,''))
    })
```

Second problem is solved by throwing AJAX-call to your backend (prior to DataTables initialization) in order to get columns definition based on your criteria (which I don't see in your original post, but, I'm sure you may adjust accordingly):

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    //get dynamically defined columns
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getcols"
    })
    .done(columns => {
        //initialize datatables
        const dataTable = $("table").DataTable({
            ...
            ajax: {
                url: "/getdata",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: columns
        });
    })
});
```

In return to calling `/getcols`, your back end must respond with valid `column`/`columnDefs` option definition, *including* `type` set to 'population' for necessary column(s), e.g.:

```
[
  { "title": "country", "data": "country" },
  { "title": "population", "data": "population", "type": "population" },
  { "title": "year", "data": "year" }
]
```

Below **live snippet** demonstrates sorting part, for complete **demo** you may examine following [sandbox](https://sdju0.sse.codesandbox.io/) with your browser's DevTools.

```js
//source data sample
const src1 = [
  {country: 'India', population: '1,368,737,513', year: 2019},
  {country: 'China', population: '1,420,062,022', year: 2019},
  {country: 'USA', population: '329,093,110', year: 2019},
  {country: 'Ukraine', population: '43,795,220', year: 2019},
  {country: 'North Korea', population: 'N/A', year: 2019},
  {country: 'Russian Federation', population: 'N/A', year: 2019}
];
//initialize datatables
const dataTable = $('table').DataTable({
  data: src1,
  dom: 't',
  columns: [
    { "title": "country", "data": "country" },
    { "title": "population", "data": "population", "type": "population" },
    { "title": "year", "data": "year" }
  ]
});
//custom sorting plug-in
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'population-asc': (a,b) => b=='N/A' ? -1: a=='N/A' ? 1 : Number(a.replace(/,/g,''))-Number(b.replace(/,/g,'')),
  'population-desc': (a,b) => b=='N/A' ? -1: a=='N/A' ? 1 : Number(b.replace(/,/g,''))-Number(a.replace(/,/g,''))
});
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script></head><body><table></table></body></html>
```

Comment: as per the query regarding (I suppose here that even though the number of columns may differ, target column appears in the same position every time): target columns may be more than one and in any position so we cannot define static target position. I have also run your code snippet but the sorting doesnot appear to be working as intended.